# Is there a better way to get this data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I use jQuery and **underscore.js**, I have `title1-2` and I would like to have the action corresponding.

```
this.items = {
    menuItems: [
        { title: 'title1',
            data: [
                { title: 'title1-1',
                    action: 'action1-1'
                },
                { title: 'title1-2',
                    action: 'action1-2'
                }
                ]
        },
        { title: 'title2',
            data: [
                { title: 'title2-1',
                    action: 'action2-1'
                },
                { title: 'title2-2',
                    action: 'action2-2'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Currently, I have the following code to do this:

```
var item = _.find(_.flatten(_.pluck(this.items.menuItems, 'data')), function (item) { return item.title === 'title1-2'; });
console.log(item.action);
```

is there a better way to find it ?

Comment: It looks fairly good to me. However, this question may be more suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Switching to [`_.chain`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#chain) would make it a bit easier to understand:

```
var item = _.chain(items.menuItems)
            .pluck('data')
            .flatten()
            .find(function(i) { return i.title === 'title1-2' })
            .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/mPa3m/

You could also skip the [`pluck`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck) and [`flatten`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#flatten) by using a [`find`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#find) inside a [`map`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#map):

```
var right_title = function(i) { return i.title === 'title1-2' };
var is_there    = function(i) { return i };
var item        = _.chain(items.menuItems)
                   .map(function(i) { return _(i.data).find(right_title) })
                   .find(is_there)
                   .value();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/uRBuZ/

Or just go old-school and use short-circuiting nested loops:

```
var i, j, sub, item;
for(i = 0, item = null; !item && i < items.menuItems.length; ++i)
    for(j = 0, sub = items.menuItems[i]; !item && j < sub.data.length; ++j)
        if(sub.data[j].title === 'title2-1')
            item = sub.data[j];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7xt5D/

This one only copies a couple of references so it should be easy on memory and it stops at the first possible opportunity so it is properly lazy as well.

If you're doing this a lot then it might make sense to build an index so that you have direct access by title:

```
var idx = { };
var i, j, sub, item;
for(i = 0, item = null; !item && i < items.menuItems.length; ++i)
    for(j = 0, sub = items.menuItems[i]; !item && j < sub.data.length; ++j)
        idx[sub.data[j].title] = sub.data[j];
console.log(idx['title1-2']);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SJuHp/

The above assumes that your titles are unique but you could switch to arrays in `idx` easily enough if that was a problem. You'd also have to track any changes to `this.items` in `idx` but that's easy if you hide it all inside an object and only go through that object's methods to work with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Clever approach, but not the most efficient as the size of the object grows ( multiple manipulations of the sub-arrays).  I think better would be to do two underscore.js finds: first for the *menuitem* matching titlex then for the *data* matching titlex-y.

```
var item = _.find(
    _.find(
        this.items.menuItems, function(item) {
            return item.title === 'title1'
        }).data,
    function(item) {
        return item.title = 'title1-2'
    });
```